# ORA-00904: "T": invalid identifier Apex Error

Tags: oracle11g, oracle-apex

I try this query in SQLDeveloper and works regular

```
   select (CASE when :Y1 = '1' then ah.kategorija_sifra when :Y1 = '2' then ah.robnagrupa_sifra when :Y1 = '3' then ah.model
when :Y1 = '6' then ah.grana when :Y1 = '7' then ah.priroda_proizvoda_sifra when :Y1 = '8' then ah.grana_proizvoda_sifra
when :Y1 = '9' then aa.nadgrupa_a when :Y1 = '10' then aa.rgrupa_a when :Y1 = '11' then aa.model_a when :Y1 = '12' then aa.osnovna_sifra end) as grupisanje
, (case when :AY1 = '1' then s.boja_osnovna  when :AY1 = '2' then s.materijal_osnovni when :AY1 = '3' then s.boja_metala  when :AY1 = '4' then s.sezona when :AY1 = '5' then s.kolekcija when :AY1 = '6' then s.nijansa_osn_boje when :AY1 = '7' then s.specificnosti_osn_materjala   when :AY1 = '8' then s.specificnosti_osn_materjala_t when :AY1 = '9' then s.godina_proizvodnje  when :AY1 = '10' then s.nijansa_boje4  end  ) as atribu1
, (case when :AY2 = '1' then s.boja_osnovna  when :AY2 = '2' then s.materijal_osnovni when :AY2 = '3' then s.boja_metala  when :AY2 = '4' then s.sezona when :AY2 = '5' then s.kolekcija when :AY2 = '6' then s.nijansa_osn_boje when :AY2 = '7' then s.specificnosti_osn_materjala   when :AY2 = '8' then s.specificnosti_osn_materjala_t when :AY2 = '9' then s.godina_proizvodnje  when :AY2 = '10' then s.nijansa_boje4  end  ) as atribu2
, (case when :AY3 = '1' then s.boja_osnovna  when :AY3 = '2' then s.materijal_osnovni when :AY3 = '3' then s.boja_metala  when :AY3 = '4' then s.sezona when :AY3 = '5' then s.kolekcija when :AY3 = '6' then s.nijansa_osn_boje when :AY3 = '7' then s.specificnosti_osn_materjala   when :AY3 = '8' then s.specificnosti_osn_materjala_t when :AY3 = '9' then s.godina_proizvodnje  when :AY3 = '10' then s.nijansa_boje4  end  ) as atribu3
, nvl(sum(p.ks_vlp),0) as ks_vlp, nvl(sum(p.ks_mlp),0) as ks_mlp
, nvl(sum(p3s.proiz),0), nvl(sum(p3s.prod_vp),0), nvl(sum(p3s.ost_vp),0), nvl(sum(p3s.kol_vp),0), nvl(sum(p3s.ps_v),0), nvl(sum(p3s.proiz_v),0), nvl(sum(p3s.prod_vp_v),0), nvl(sum(p3s.ost_vp_v),0), nvl(sum(p3s.popust_vp),0), nvl(sum(p3s.poslato),0)  
, nvl(sum(p3s.primljeno),0), nvl(sum(p3s.prod_mp),0), nvl(sum(p3s.ost_mp),0), nvl(sum(p3s.kol_mp),0)
from

(select sifra, velicina,nvl(sum(vlp),0)+nvl(sum(put_vlp),0) as ks_vlp , nvl(sum(mlp),0)+nvl(sum(put_mlp),0) as ks_mlp
from mona_internal.zal_3b_savke
where datum between to_date('01'||substr(:P405,4,8),'dd.mm.yyyy') and :P405
group by sifra, velicina) p

------------------------------------------------------------ Krajnja stanja -------------------------------------------

left join mona_internal.artikli_hijerarhija ah
on p.sifra=ah.artikal_sifra

---------------------------------------------------------- Artikli hijerarhija -----------------------------------------

left join dwh.bck_svojstva s
on s.artikal_sifra= ah.artikal_sifra

---------------------------------------------------------- Svojstva  -----------------------------------------

left join mona_internal.artikli_analiza aa
on aa.sifra=ah.artikal_sifra

---------------------------------------------------------- Artikli analiza -----------------------------------------

left join (
select datum, sifra, velicina
, nvl(sum(proiz),0) proiz, nvl(sum(prod_vp),0) prod_vp, nvl(sum(ost_vp),0) ost_vp, nvl(sum(kol_vp),0) kol_vp, nvl(sum(ps_v),0) ps_v
, nvl(sum(proiz_v),0) proiz_v, nvl(sum(prod_vp_v),0) prod_vp_v, nvl(sum(ost_vp_v),0) ost_vp_v, nvl(sum(popust_vp),0) popust_vp, nvl(sum(poslato),0) as poslato         /* --vlp iz 3bsira*/
, nvl(sum(primljeno),0) primljeno, nvl(sum(prod_mp),0) prod_mp, nvl(sum(ost_mp),0) ost_mp, nvl(sum(kol_mp),0) as kol_mp                                          /* --mlp  iz 3bsira*/
from mona_internal.PROMET_3B_SIRA
where datum between :P305 and :P405
group by datum, sifra, velicina) p3s
on p3s.sifra=ah.artikal_sifra

left join (
select sifra, velicina, sum(vlp)+sum(put_vlp) as vlp, sum(mlp)+sum(put_mlp) as mlp from mona_internal.zal_3b_savke
where (datum between to_date('01'||substr(:P305,4,8),'dd.mm.yyyy')
and case when to_date('01'||substr(:P305,4,8),'dd.mm.yyyy') = :P305 then  to_date(:P305, 'dd.mm.yyyy')  when to_date('01'||substr(:P305,4,8),'dd.mm.yyyy') != :P305 then to_date(:P305, 'dd.mm.yyyy') - 1 end )
and  jeps like (case when to_date('01'||substr(:P305,4,8),'dd.mm.yyyy') = :P305 then  'D' else  '%'  end)
group by sifra, velicina) ps
on ps.sifra=ah.artikal_sifra

---------------------------------------------------------- Pocetna stanja   -----------------------------------------


group by
 (CASE when :Y1 = '1' then ah.kategorija_sifra when :Y1 = '2' then ah.robnagrupa_sifra when :Y1 = '3' then ah.model
when :Y1 = '6' then ah.grana when :Y1 = '7' then ah.priroda_proizvoda_sifra when :Y1 = '8' then ah.grana_proizvoda_sifra
when :Y1 = '9' then aa.nadgrupa_a when :Y1 = '10' then aa.rgrupa_a when :Y1 = '11' then aa.model_a when :Y1 = '12' then aa.osnovna_sifra end)
, (case when :AY1 = '1' then s.boja_osnovna  when :AY1 = '2' then s.materijal_osnovni when :AY1 = '3' then s.boja_metala  when :AY1 = '4' then s.sezona when :AY1 = '5' then s.kolekcija when :AY1 = '6' then s.nijansa_osn_boje when :AY1 = '7' then s.specificnosti_osn_materjala   when :AY1 = '8' then s.specificnosti_osn_materjala_t when :AY1 = '9' then s.godina_proizvodnje  when :AY1 = '10' then s.nijansa_boje4  end  ) 
, (case when :AY2 = '1' then s.boja_osnovna  when :AY2 = '2' then s.materijal_osnovni when :AY2 = '3' then s.boja_metala  when :AY2 = '4' then s.sezona when :AY2 = '5' then s.kolekcija when :AY2 = '6' then s.nijansa_osn_boje when :AY2 = '7' then s.specificnosti_osn_materjala   when :AY2 = '8' then s.specificnosti_osn_materjala_t when :AY2 = '9' then s.godina_proizvodnje  when :AY2 = '10' then s.nijansa_boje4  end  )
, (case when :AY3 = '1' then s.boja_osnovna  when :AY3 = '2' then s.materijal_osnovni when :AY3 = '3' then s.boja_metala  when :AY3 = '4' then s.sezona when :AY3 = '5' then s.kolekcija when :AY3 = '6' then s.nijansa_osn_boje when :AY3 = '7' then s.specificnosti_osn_materjala   when :AY3 = '8' then s.specificnosti_osn_materjala_t when :AY3 = '9' then s.godina_proizvodnje  when :AY3 = '10' then s.nijansa_boje4  end  ) ;
```

But when the same query input in APEX, it return to me:
 **ORA-00904: "T": invalid identifier**

I found many cases on google, but none with this problem. Strange is, that works in Developer, but not works in APEX.

Any idea?

P.S.

1.) Parameters P305 and P405 are in APEX items-date picker

2.) Parameter Y1 is LOV and has values 
 (STATIC:Nadgrupa;1,RGrupa;2,Model;3,Grana;6,prir_proiz_sif;7,grana_proiz_sif;8,
  nadgrupa_a;9,rgrupa_a;10,model_a;11,osn_sifra_a;12)

3.) Parameters AY1, AY2, AY3 are also LOV and have same values 
 (STATIC:boja_osnovna;1,materijal_osnovni;2,boja_metala;3,sezona;4,kolekcija;5,n
 ijansa_osn_boje;6,specificnosti_osn_materjala;7,T_specificnosti_osn_materijala;
 8,godina_proizvodnje;9,godina_sezone;10)

Comment: Try simplifying the query by removing parts of it until the error goes away - at least then you'll have some idea where it occurs.

Comment: A wild guess, you seemed to mention ,T_specificnosti_osn_materijala for 8 while I see 'specificnosti_osn_materjala_t' for 8, Could that be it?

Answer (score 0):

Try reduce the 'T_specificnosti_osn_materijala' by one or two chars..

Answer (score 0):

Which Apex version do you use?

The fact is: in prior Apex versions, you could have used up to 4000 characters in any (PL/)SQL unit because it was a VARCHAR2(4000) data type column. Your code exceeds that limit, i.e. it appears that Apex took substring of your code, up to 4000 characters, and stored it into its tables. Trying to execute such an "invalid" statement results with an error.

As this SELECT statement uses page items, you can't create a view and use it as a source on your Apex page. However, you might try to create a table function whose IN parameters are Apex page items' values.

What are table functions? They return PL/SQL collection, and you can use them in a FROM clause using the TABLE operator. Have a look at the following example:

```
SQL> CREATE TYPE t_tf_row AS OBJECT
  2  (
  3     empno NUMBER,
  4     ename VARCHAR2 (20)
  5  );
  6  /

Type created.

SQL> CREATE TYPE t_tf_tab IS TABLE OF t_tf_row;
  2  /

Type created.

SQL> CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION f_test (par_deptno IN NUMBER)
  2     RETURN t_Tf_tab
  3  IS
  4     l_tab   t_tf_tab := t_tf_tab ();
  5  BEGIN
  6     FOR cur_r IN (SELECT empno, ename
  7                     FROM emp
  8                    WHERE deptno = par_Deptno)
  9     LOOP
 10        l_tab.EXTEND;
 11        l_tab (l_tab.LAST) := t_tf_row (cur_r.empno, cur_r.ename);
 12     END LOOP;
 13
 14     RETURN l_tab;
 15  END;
 16  /

Function created.

SQL> select * From table(f_test(20));

     EMPNO ENAME
---------- --------------------
      7566 JONES
      7788 SCOTT
      7902 FORD
      7369 SMITH
      7876 ADAMS

SQL>
```

You'd use the same SELECT statement in Apex.

Another obvious option is to upgrade to the most recent Apex version (by the way, how come you didn't do it yet?).